# change css class based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I have the following HTML

```
<header class="fixed">...</header>
<div id="content">
    <div id="sidemenu" class="fixed">...</div>
    <div id="scroll">...</div>
</div>
<footer class="fixed">...</footer>
```

With various positioning rules in the CSS and the rule

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

This achieves the desired affect of only the div with id scroll moves. However, this can leaves the footer out of view.

What I want to do, is once the bottom of the scroll div reaches the bottom of the footer, change `position: fixed` to `position: absolute` and then everything will scroll up together revealing the footer.

But I don't know how to do it. I was looking at [waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints) but I'm in a little over my head.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should solve the problem of yours. try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollBottom <= $("footer").height()) {
        $("footer").css("position", "absolute");
        } 
        else {
            $("footer").css("position", "fixed");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For that, you will have 'onScroll' event. And check when the coordinates of the scroll div matches that of the  footer. As soon as they match, change the position to 'absolute' in the implementation of handler.